# How to access annotation present in super class using ELEMENT.TYPE field in java

Tags: java

I have A1 class. A1 class extends A2 and A2 extends A3. I have 2 annotation @t1,@t2, which is declared in all the 3 class. To access annotation if i use method like this :

```
public void checkAnnotation(Object s1, Object d1) {
    Field[] field1= source.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : field1) {
        if ((!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) && field.isAnnotationPresent(t1.class)) 
                || (!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) && field.isAnnotationPresent(t2.class))) {
            t1 tx= field.getAnnotation(t1.class);
            t2 tc = field.getAnnotation(t2.class);
            if (((tx!= null) && (tx.isread())) || (tc!= null)) {
                try {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object attributeValue1 = field.get(s1);
                    field.set(d1, attributeValue1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printstackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How to get super class declared fields .? In this example i can get it only for s1 class. not super class of s1. Please provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getSuperClass()` to get the super class of a `Class` object.